# Go module file version issue missing latest changes

Tags: go, version, software-design, go-modules, incompatibility

I have a situation where i work with 3 artifacts build and deployed differently.

- Artifact 1 has my latest changes,
- Artifact 2 and 3 download artifact 1 as a module.

With:

- Artifact 2 has to make a GRPC call to Artifact 3 to access data,
- Artifact 3 has an older version of artifact 1 compared to artifact 2.

Now:

- Artifact 2 validates against artifact 1 before making the GRPC call to artifact 3,
- artifact 3 also makes similar validation against artifact 1 before it completes the transaction.

Problem: Validation in artifact 2 passed but fails in artifact 3, because of older version.
Current code throw exception which is tried max no. of times.

I can think of keeping the artifacts in sync however there is no way i can be sure it is going to stay same.

What are the ways these kind of incompatibilities are dealt with so not all requests fail or produce unexpected/inconsistent results?

Answer (score 0):

You would either:

- develop and release all three artifact together
- or release one big artifact, able to be configured at runtime as a server (old Artifact1), sender (old Artifact2) or client (old Artifact3)

In both option, this is a distribution issue that you cannot always control: how to ensure the right version is deployed in the right place?

That means the actual solution is to ensure [backward compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility), allowing the server to return older versions of your GRPC message.